# Standalone pandoc executable for Windows

Tags: tfs, pandoc, azure-devops

Does there exist a standalone pandoc executable for Windows?

I want to parse documentation (markdown to HTML) during our builds, but our build agent host does not belong to us and thus we cannot preeinstall any software. We could just check in the executable into source control.

We are using VSO (TFS) for those interested.

Comment: Have you tried installing it on your local windows machine, then copying over the binary found at `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Pandoc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc is a single executable. You can install the package and copy `pandoc.exe` or you can extract the file from the MSI using Orca.